# Reduced homology: $\tilde H_n(X \cup CA) \approx H_n(X \cup CA, CA)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

On Hatcher 125, it says $$\tilde H_n(X \cup CA) \approx H_n(X \cup CA, CA).$$ I couldn't really see this from my understanding of reduced homology, it is just replacing
$$\dots \stackrel{\partial_{n+1}}{\longrightarrow} C_n \stackrel{\partial_{n}}{\longrightarrow} C_{n-1} \stackrel{\partial_{n-1}}{\longrightarrow} \dots \stackrel{\partial_{1}}{\longrightarrow} C_0 \stackrel{\partial_{0}}{\longrightarrow} 0$$
with $$\dots \stackrel{\partial_{n+1}}{\longrightarrow} C_n \stackrel{\partial_{n}}{\longrightarrow} C_{n-1} \stackrel{\partial_{n-1}}{\longrightarrow} \dots \stackrel{\partial_{1}}{\longrightarrow} C_0 \stackrel{\epsilon}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow 0.$$

Following above, I can't see why $\tilde H_n(X \cup CA) \approx H_n(X \cup CA, CA)$?

---

Is it just because $CA$ is contractible, hence quotient $CA$ is trivial?

Comment: Yes CA is contractible so maybe look at the reduced long exact sequence of the pair $X \cup CA, CA$.

Comment: I believe you need A to be a deformation retract of an open neighborhood for this to hold.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just because $CA$ is contractible, hence quotient $CA$ is trivial.